# How to split model between 2 GPUs with keras in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Essentially, I am looking for something like `with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'` for keras. I want to put my operations on different GPUs. I am using a Sequential model following lines of

```
...
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
...

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
```

Comment: Why don't just use multi_gpu_model? Or am I missing smth?

Comment: @sharky multi_gpu_model is the data-parallel approach, I am going for model-parallel

Comment: I'm aware of that, just wanted to know what are specific reasons you want model parallelism. And wouldn't it work the way you described, `with tf.device(`? Afaik, you can simple place specific layers on different devices and model.fit will do the rest

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `with K.tf.device('/gpu:1'):` as a context. Or, if the backend is tensorflow, then the way you assign gpu in tf should work for keras also.